# Как сохранить модель в forms.Form django?

Tags: python, django

Я сохраняю форму через `forms.Form`, поскольку мне нужен свой `queryset`. Куда указывать поле `related_uuid` из модели? в `save` или после создания класса? если после создания класса, тогда мне надо делать как поле `hidden`? (это поле не должно отображаться на сайте)

текст ошибки: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'related_uuid'`

вопрос тупой, я знаю, но почему-то не могу решить

**Views**

```
def saveForm(self, **kwargs):   
        form_add = RelatedAddForm(self.request.POST, prefix='form')
        form_add.related_uuid = kwargs['uuid']
        form_add.save()
```

**Forms**

```
class RelatedAddForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autocomplete': 'on'}), queryset=None)
    # сюда указывать related_uuid?
    # related_uuid = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial='value', required=False)
​
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RelatedAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].queryset = getStoresListByUser()
​
​
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        StoreRelated.objects.update_or_create(store=name, related_uuid=related_uuid)
​
```

**Models**

```
class StoreRelated(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey('Storehouses', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    related_uuid = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
​
class Storehouses(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Не надо создавать метод save, а просто передать данные в модель

```
def saveForm(self, **kwargs):
    related_dict = kwargs['related_dict']
    form_from_dict = related_dict['form']
    f = StoreRelated(
        store=form_from_dict.cleaned_data['name'],
        related_uuid=related_dict['uuid'])
    f.save()
```